# Redirect with trailing slash in netlify

Tags: netlify, trailing-slash

i've have a gatsby site deployed on netlify. I'm trying to make a 200 redirect to a external landing page (hosted on netlify aswell) but its not seem to work out:

/abm https://some-domain.com.br/abm/:splat 301

If i make a 200 redirect, this works fine. With /abm/* works too, but if i  don't add a trailing slash at the end, the landing page brokes (images, css and js). Is there a way to make something like this? where i still make a 200 and my landing page still serves assets without the trailing slash at the end.

my goal:
/abm https://some-domain.com.br/abm/ 200

Comment: check your redirect rules on [netlify playground](https://play.netlify.com/).

Comment: @Pedro Dalmolin you ever figure this out?

Comment: @mheavers no...  i just configured the links href manually, like /about/ etc